# Cannot use subroutine name in socket created by Perl RPC::Serialized::Server::NetServer::Single

Tags: perl, serversocket

I want to use Perl module and wrap it into a standalone socket which would publish the subroutines from the module to other programmes. However, I probably cannot overcome namespace issues, since in the client script, I am still getting an error message:
RPC::Serialized::X::Application\',\'MESSAGE\' => \'No handler for 'predejPOS' .

My server script:

```
use RPC::Serialized::Server::NetServer::Single;
use RPC::Serialized::Handler::HashTree;

my $s = RPC::Serialized::Server::NetServer::Single->new({
    net_server => {log_file => '', port => 20203 },
    rpc_serialized => {handler_namespaces => ''},
});

$s->run;
```

My client script:

```
use RPC::Serialized::Client::INET;

my $client = RPC::Serialized::Client::INET->new({
  io_socket_inet => {PeerAddr  => '127.0.0.1', PeerPort => 20203,}
});

my $result = $client->predejPOS('flu-like');
```

My module (HastTree.pm):

```
package  RPC::Serialized::Handler::HashTree;

require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(predejPOS);

use base 'RPC::Serialized::Handler';

our $VERSION = '0.01';

sub predejPOS {
  my %POS;
  $POS{'flu-like'}='<JJ>';
  return $POS{$_[0]};
};

1;
```

I am using Windows 7, Strawberry Perl 5.12.3, and the module sits on the correct address
(C:\PROGS\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\RPC\Serialized\Handler). The function predejPOS is recognised inside the server script (ie. I can print its result from it), but I cannot access it through the client-server communication. I assume that it has something to do with the subtle difference between calling the function and calling the method. I am afraid that it is probably something simple, but even after a substantial effort and googling I was not able to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well I eventually solved it by myself:

First, I got completely wrong the concept of calling functions - over the network you can only call so called **RPC Handlers**. Moreover for each handler there must be a module in RPC::Serialized::Handler directory with the same name and a specific structure with only one subroutine inside called invoke(). Thus I changed my module (named now 'PredejPOS.pm') to:

```
package RPC::Serialized::Handler::PredejPOS;
{
  $RPC::Serialized::Handler::PredejPOS::VERSION = '0.01';
}

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use base 'RPC::Serialized::Handler';

sub invoke {
    my $self = shift;
    my $key = shift;

    my %POS;
    $POS{'flu-like'}='<JJ>';

    return scalar $POS{$key};
}

1;
```

But it was still not working.
Finally secondly I found that under Windows environment, the Perl Data::Serialize module does not work properly.
In the package Serialized.pm, subroutine recv (row 115), the chomp does not remove the damned Windows line ending '\cM'. When I corrected it, it started working as envisaged. Actually there is a lenghty discussion of this behaviour here ( http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=549385 )

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For object method the first argument is always the current object instance itself. Sorry, if I am not clear enough, try to figure out the difference from this example:

Try this:

```
sub predejPOS {
  my $self = shift; 
  my $key  = shift; 
  my %POS;
  $POS{'flu-like'}='<JJ>';
  return $POS{$key};
};
```

Comment: Nope, that is not the problem. I may not be writing the subroutine in the pure Perl tradition, but calling of the function works inside the server script (and if I modify it your way, it stops working) - I can, as a part of server script, print predejPOS('flu-like') and it will print correctly '<JJ>'.